# Power series end up with $\ln(-\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I am trying to find the radius of convergence of the power series $$a_n=\frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n.$$

Using Hadamard's formula, we have that $$R=\frac{1}{\limsup|\frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}|^\frac{1}{n}}$$

So to compute this, we take the logarithm and raise everything to the $e$ then apply l'hopital's rule giving

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}
=e^{\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left(n^{2}\right)-\ln \left(4^{n}+3 n\right)}{n}}=e^{\ln (0-\infty)}
=e^{\ln(-\infty)} =0$$

However I have ended up with $\ln(-\infty)$ which is undefined. Where did my resasoning go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2}{4^n+3n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n^2)^\frac{1}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{3n}{4^n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: For those wondering, the last inequality come from computing the numerator and the denominator of the limit separately. The numerator is $[n^{1/n}]^2\to 1^2=1$. The denominator is $e^{\frac{0}{\infty}}\to 1$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician. Let me, please, suggest for denominator inequalities $1<1+\frac{3n}{4^n}<2$. Now, knowing $2^{\frac{1}{n}}\to 1, n \to \infty$, we obtain result using sandwich.

Comment: B.t.w, silent down voters are welcome to express arguments, if have any, especially, when answer is correct.